# How to get distinct values for list returned by MDX?

Tags: distinct, mdx

I have an MDX query that returns a list of values where there is redundancy. I'd like to get the distinct values. I've tried using the Distinct function in several ways but it is not working.

Here is the query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MU] AS 
    Mid
    (
      Right
      (
        [AG].[Dept].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
       ,4
      )
     ,
      Instr(Right([AG].[Dept].CurrentMember.Member_Caption,4),"_") + 1
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[MU]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[AG].[MU].Children HAVING 
  [Measures].[MU] <> "tive" ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```

The third line is basically taking a string and getting the last part of it. The children part focuses on the part of the hierarchy I'm concerned with. The Having part filters out a value from the list.

Currently the results look like this:

```
F
A
B
C
C
D
E
A
E
F
C
```

I would like the list to be like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Please help.

---

Edit

Adding an `AdvWrks` example:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[aLetter] AS 
      Left
      (
        [Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
       ,1
      )

SELECT 
  {[Measures].[aLetter]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Geography].[Country].[Country].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works] ;
```

It returns the following and I think the aim of the game is to change the script so that either U.K or U.S.A are not included:

[image]

Comment: ...I added an `AdvWrks` version - hope I didn't mess up your question?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a technique that is working against the AdvWrks cube:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[aLetter] AS 
    Left
    (
      [Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
     ,1
    ) 
  SET [orderGeo] AS 
    Order
    (
      [Geography].[Country].[Country].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[aLetter]
     ,BDESC
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[aRk] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [Geography].[Country].CurrentMember
     ,[orderGeo]
     ,[Measures].[aLetter]
    ) 
  SET [distinctCountries] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [orderGeo] AS x
     ,
      x.CurrentOrdinal = [Measures].[aRk]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[aLetter] ON 0
 ,[distinctCountries] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: whytheq - Nice attempt.

Comment: @SouravA - it works and I quite like it - unfortunately another mdx effort with no feedback from questioner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GENERATE` to weed out duplicates from a set. My Adventure Works server is down, so here is one simple example in my current cube server.

```
WITH SET duplicates AS
{
 [Client].[Status].&[Current],
 [Client].[Status].&[Current],
 [Client].[Status].&[Terminated],
 [Client].[Status].&[Terminated]
}


SET noduplicates AS 
    GENERATE
        (
            duplicates, 
            {[Client].[Status].CURRENTMEMBER}
        )

SELECT noduplicates ON 1,
{} ON 0
FROM [SomeCube]
```

The members will be naturally ordered(as specified in the cube design). If you want a specific sorting, you would have to throw in an `ORDER` clause.

Note: `GENERATE` can also retain duplicates if the third argument is provided as `ALL`.